# show marker in a google map in javaFX desktop app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, javafx

I´ve got a question about JavaScript and GoogleMaps!

I´m trying to load a google map and show the position of a driver on it in a JavaFX application.
My knowedge about JavaScript == null.
I have a WebView, a ComboBox and a Button.
The button shows the poition of the selected driver in the ComboBox.

I´m able to show the map and the first marker, but i can´t show other markers, the perfect thig would be to be able to show only one or (if the selected item is "All") shows all drivers.

here is my code:

JavaFX file:

```
public class MapController  implements Initializable{

@FXML
Button changeConductorButton;

@FXML
ComboBox<String> conductorComboBox;

@FXML
WebView mapaWebView;

WebEngine engine;

double lat;
double lon;
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    fillComboBoxConductor();
    final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("googlemapscript.html");
    engine = mapaWebView.getEngine();
    lat = 22.46589;
    lon =   -22.35939;
    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        engine.executeScript("" + 
                                "window.lat = " + lat + ";" +
                                "window.lon = " + lon + ";" +
                                "document.goToLocation(window.lat, window.lon);"
                                );
                    }
                }
            });

    engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
}

private void fillComboBoxConductor() {
    //code to fill ComboBox
}

@FXML
private void changeConductor(){
    lat = lat+5;
    lon = lon + 5;
    engine = mapaWebView.getEngine();
    engine.executeScript("addMarker("+lat+","+lon+");");
    System.out.println("added marker");
}
```

}

and my hmtl file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Java-Buddy: Google Maps</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
    #mapcanvas {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%
    }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Java-Buddy: Google Maps</h1>
    <div id="mapcanvas">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.map = new google.maps.Map(document
                    .getElementById("mapcanvas"));
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.857908, 10.598997);
            var Options = {
                zoom : 15,
                center : latlng,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"),
                    Options);
            //var carMarkerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/images/car.png');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(35.857908, 10.598997),
                map : map,
                draggable : false,
                //icon: carMarkerImage,
                title : "",
                autoPan : true

            });
            var nombreconductor = "Victor"
            var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content : nombreconductor
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                infobulle.open(map, marker);
            });


            document.goToLocation = function(x, y) {
                alert("goToLocation, x: " + x + ", y:" + y);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
                marker.setPosition(latLng);
                map.setCenter(latLng);
            }


            // Function for adding a marker to the page.
           function addMarker(x,y) {
            var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            marker.setPosition(latLng2);
        }

        </script>


    </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

Now i´m trying to show several markers at the same time, i´ve an array where i push the several locations
I fill an array from JavaFX app and call to a function to show the points:

```
@FXML
private void showAllConductores(){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        lat = lat+5;
        lon = lon + 5;
        engine.executeScript("arrayConductores.push({x:5, y:3});");

    }
    engine.executeScript("addAllMarkers();");

}
```

And in the html file:

```
        // Function for adding a marker to the page.
        function addMarker(x, y) {
            var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            marker.setPosition(latLng2);
            alert("addMarker JAVAScript, x: " + x + ", y:" + y);
        }
        var arrayConductores = [];
        function addAllMarkers() {
            for ( var x in arrayConductores) {
                addMarker(x.x,x.y);
                console.error('message');
            }
        }
```

But does not appear anything...

Comment: If you deal with the markers after you created them(like hiding, redisplating,etc.), it is best to hold marker objects on an array. Otherwise, changing global `marker` object in `addMarker()` function to local will probably solve your problem: `var marker ...`

Comment: Solved for one marker! I´ll edit the answer now!
Now i´m tryin to show a group of markers passin a string of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will add multiple markers, let all markers be created in `addMarker()` function. Move infobubbles into the function so that each marker has unique infobubble:

```
....

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"),
                Options);

document.goToLocation = function(x, y) {
    alert("goToLocation, x: " + x + ", y:" + y);
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    map.setCenter(latLng);
    // Since you have multiple markers, markers will remain as they are
}

function addMarker(x, y) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position : new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
       map : map,
       draggable : false,
       //icon: carMarkerImage,
       title : "",
       autoPan : true
    });

    var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       // You can pass some content to the function like addMarker(x, y, content)
       content : "some content for your marker"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
       infobulle.open(map, marker);
    });
}

addMarker(35.857908, 10.598997);

...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i´ve updated the question to show more than one markers

Comment: Your `addMarker()` function only changes first marker's current position, doesn't add a new marker. Second, in `showAllConductores()`, you are pushing 3 as latitude and 5 as longitude in for loop each turn, so before modifying your code again, can you check is there any marker at position (3, 5)? Do your alerts and console messages work properly?

Comment: @vlopezla I have no knowledge about JavaFX, but I wrote your code in pastebin as I thought, check: http://pastebin.com/XELUun5v . There may be syntax errors, but it should give an idea about how javascript side should be.